# Using sudo apt-get update

Tags: apt, updates

when I am using `sudo apt-get update`, I am getting the following as output and hence I am not able to install git send-email package.

```
Err http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en_IN                         
  Connection failed [IP: 216.58.220.46 80]
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
  Connection failed
Err http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner Sources                       
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.191 80]
Err http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en                            
  Connection failed [IP: 216.58.220.46 80]
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Sources                              
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.152 80]
Err http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner amd64 Packages                
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.191 80]
Err http://dl.google.com stable/main amd64 Packages                            
  Connection failed [IP: 216.58.220.46 80]
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main amd64 Packages                       
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.152 80]
Err http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner i386 Packages                 
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.191 80]
Err http://dl.google.com stable/main i386 Packages                             
  Connection failed [IP: 216.58.220.46 80]
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main i386 Packages                        
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.152 80]
Err http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner Translation-en_IN             
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.191 80]
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en_IN
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.152 80]
Err http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner Translation-en                
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.191 80]
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en                       
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.152 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Sources   
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Sources
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Sources
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Sources
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main amd64 Packages
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted amd64 Packages
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe amd64 Packages
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse amd64 Packages
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main i386 Packages
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted i386 Packages
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe i386 Packages
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse i386 Packages
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en_IN
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en 
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Translation-en_IN
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Translation-en
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Translation-en_IN
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Translation-en
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Translation-en_IN
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Translation-en
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Sources
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Sources
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Sources
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Sources
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/main amd64 Packages
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted amd64 Packages
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe amd64 Packages
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/main i386 Packages
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted i386 Packages
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe i386 Packages
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse i386 Packages
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Translation-en_IN
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Translation-en
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Translation-en_IN
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Translation-en
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Translation-en_IN
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Translation-en
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Translation-en_IN
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Translation-en
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Sources
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Sources
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Sources
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Sources
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe amd64 Packages
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main i386 Packages
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted i386 Packages
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe i386 Packages
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Translation-en_IN
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Translation-en
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Translation-en_IN
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Translation-en
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Translation-en_IN
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Translation-en
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Translation-en_IN
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Translation-en
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main Sources
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted Sources
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe Sources
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse Sources
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main amd64 Packages
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted amd64 Packages
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe amd64 Packages
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main i386 Packages
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted i386 Packages
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe i386 Packages
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse i386 Packages
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main Translation-en_IN
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main Translation-en
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse Translation-en_IN
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse Translation-en
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted Translation-en_IN
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted Translation-en
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe Translation-en_IN
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe Translation-en
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/Release.gpg  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/Release.gpg  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.191 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/Release.gpg  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.152 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Connection failed

W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/talkplugin/deb/dists/stable/Release.gpg  Connection failed [IP: 216.58.220.46 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/Release.gpg  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.152 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.152 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.152 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/i18n/Translation-en_IN  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.152 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/i18n/Translation-en  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.152 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/Release.gpg  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/partner/source/Sources  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.191 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/partner/binary-amd64/Packages  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.191 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/partner/binary-i386/Packages  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.191 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/partner/i18n/Translation-en_IN  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.191 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/partner/i18n/Translation-en  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.191 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/i18n/Translation-en_IN  Connection failed

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/i18n/Translation-en  Connection failed

W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/talkplugin/deb/dists/stable/main/i18n/Translation-en_IN  Connection failed [IP: 216.58.220.46 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/talkplugin/deb/dists/stable/main/i18n/Translation-en  Connection failed [IP: 216.58.220.46 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/Release.gpg  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Connection failed

W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/talkplugin/deb/dists/stable/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Connection failed [IP: 216.58.220.46 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  Connection failed

W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/talkplugin/deb/dists/stable/main/binary-i386/Packages  Connection failed [IP: 216.58.220.46 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/restricted/source/Sources  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/universe/source/Sources  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/multiverse/source/Sources  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/universe/binary-i386/Packages  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/i18n/Translation-en_IN  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/i18n/Translation-en  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en_IN  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/restricted/i18n/Translation-en_IN  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/restricted/i18n/Translation-en  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/universe/i18n/Translation-en_IN  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/universe/i18n/Translation-en  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/main/source/Sources  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/restricted/source/Sources  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/universe/source/Sources  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/multiverse/source/Sources  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/main/binary-i386/Packages  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/universe/binary-i386/Packages  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/main/i18n/Translation-en_IN  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/main/i18n/Translation-en  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en_IN  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/restricted/i18n/Translation-en_IN  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/restricted/i18n/Translation-en  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/universe/i18n/Translation-en_IN  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/universe/i18n/Translation-en  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/main/source/Sources  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/restricted/source/Sources  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/universe/source/Sources  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/multiverse/source/Sources  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/main/binary-i386/Packages  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/universe/binary-i386/Packages  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/main/i18n/Translation-en_IN  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/main/i18n/Translation-en  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en_IN  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/restricted/i18n/Translation-en_IN  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/restricted/i18n/Translation-en  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/universe/i18n/Translation-en_IN  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/universe/i18n/Translation-en  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/main/source/Sources  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/restricted/source/Sources  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/universe/source/Sources  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/multiverse/source/Sources  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/main/binary-i386/Packages  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/universe/binary-i386/Packages  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/main/i18n/Translation-en_IN  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/main/i18n/Translation-en  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en_IN  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/restricted/i18n/Translation-en_IN  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/restricted/i18n/Translation-en  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/universe/i18n/Translation-en_IN  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/universe/i18n/Translation-en  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

When I am using cat gedit /etc/apt/sources.list,I am getting the following:
[image]

Comment: can you add the output of `cat gedit /etc/apt/sources.list` to your question? Probably changing the mirror will work for you . See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu#Download_Server to know how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell what's wrong from just that information. Are you able to access other websites? Are you behind a proxy? Have you tried `sudo apt-get clean`? You can also open up `Software and Updates` and choose one of the many mirrors to download updates from.

If you're behind a proxy, edit or create the file `/etc/apt/apt.conf` and insert your proxy settings:
`Acquire::http::Proxy "http://<proxy_host>:<proxy_port>";`

Comment: What does behind a proxy means?

Comment: It's basically another computer through which your internet requests are processed. Here's the wiki: [Proxy Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server)

Answer (score 1):

some time ago a friend with Linux Mint 13 (based on Ubuntu 12.04) had the same error (web was accessable, but all repositories and also the mirrors seemed to be offline)... and i tried nearly everything but nothing worked!

so the last thing before i gave up was trying to uncheck all sources (don't ask me why), close , do a `sudo apt-get update` and then enabled the same sources again, do a `sudo apt-get update` again and everything worked like it should!

[image: Software Sources]

Answer (score -1):

1. Make sure you're connected to Internet.
2. Do `sudo apt-get clean` and `sudo apt-get autoclean`. Now, try doing the update again.
3. If that doesn't work, consider installing `aptitude`.